# Suppressing Vimdiff message

Tags: bash, scripting, vim, vimdiff

I tried looking online and it seems that no one has a simple answer to it.

In my bash script, I use vimdiff for two files, 
but after I close the vimdiff it shows *"2 files to edit"* whenever the files differ.
**It seems like no one has the solution to this**
I was wondering if there was a short way in my bash script 
to suppress that message not through .vimrc edits.

Comment: If you found an answer that does use an edit to a vimrc you can pass it in on the command line using `--cmd`.

Comment: what's the purpose to use vimdiff? There is an option in diff which displays files side by side. For example `diff -y file1 file2`

Comment: Where does that "2 files to edit" message show? Back in the shell? In Vim before you exit? In Vim after you exit?

Comment: Yup. @FDinoff, that's the way to go!

Comment: @BMW: Perhaps for syntax highlighting? Or for the ability to copy changes between files?

Comment: @Ben: It's emitted to the terminal on startup and is visible when Vim exits.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at [Vim 7.4.265's startup code](https://code.google.com/p/vim/source/browse/src/main.c?name=v7-4-265#523), there is no way to suppress the `%d files to edit` message being emitted to the terminal (and hence being visible after exit) when invoked as `vimdiff`.

I guess you could always submit a patch to suppress this message with a switch.

---

### Update

I knew there would be a way to get the result you desired (without writing C)!

Invoke Vim as `vim` with *one* file argument. And then call [`:diffsplit`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/diff.html#%3adiffsplit) on the second file. But from the command-line, via [`-c`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#-c):

```
vim /path/to/first_file -c'diffsplit /path/to/second_file'
```

Comment: The biggest problem I had using the -c flag is that I couldn't get it to properly handle a path with a space for the second file. I tried escaping it in every way that I could think of, and couldn't get it to work. I've added a different solution which gets around this problem by using the -d flag and sending output to /dev/null.